# Retrieve video file from mysql database using php and save it to local folder

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to upload video files to `mysql` database and retrieve those files and save it in a local folder. My table simply consists of id, a title of video, and size of video.

I thought both of retrieving from and uploading to database would be easy. I don't see any error except that undefined variable thing for `$_GET["download"]` once I run the code but the folder where all the videos should be saved is always empty.

`PHP` code saving a video file that I retrieve from database to a local folder:

```
if($_GET["download"] == 1)
{
    $query = "select id, videoName, videoFile from video where ID = 5";
    $result = $dab->sql_query($query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_FILES["size"] = $row["videoFile"];
    $_FILES["tmp_name"] = $row["videoName"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tmp_name"], "download/" . "sample.mp4");
}
```

HTML a tag:

```
<html lang = "en">
<body>
        <a id = "download" href = "main2.php?download=1">download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tmp_name"], "download/" . "sample.mp4");
```

make sure about this path and Check if the download/ dir is writeable.

Comment: I used if(is_writable(dirname("download/"))) to check that download directory is writable and it returned true. so I removed that . "sample.mp4" and ran the code again but it still did not let me save the file.